# v-bind on link href does not work but only in production (Nuxt static site)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I am trying to bind a generated link to a button. The link is generated based on parameters passed in the URL. The code roughly looks like this:

```
      <a :href="generated_link">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="button"
        >
          Go to Link
        </button>
      </a>
```

The code to generate the link:

```
mounted() {

let route_variables = {
  cmpid: this.$route.query.cmpid,
  utm_source: this.$route.query.utm_source,
};

if (route_variables["cmpid"] === undefined) {
  console.log(route_variables["cmpid"]);
  route_variables["cmpid"] = "2983928372983";
}

var newLink = "https://www.website/?";
for (const property in route_variables) {
  if (route_variables[property] != undefined) {
    newLink += property + "=" + route_variables[property] + "&";
  }
}
this.generated_link = newLink;
},
```

In development, the link is populated properly. When I add a cmpid variable to the URL then it is appended to the button link as expected. In deployment, however, the cmpid variable is always set to the value I have set as the default when there is no variable in the URL, even when I add it to the URL. I think that this is because it is being evaluated in build time. If I just use ((generated_link}} to print the link on the page it works fine. I have tried a bunch of different workarounds to try to get the a tag to render client-side to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you saying, in production, that the `href` in `<a :href="generated_link">` is wrong when you inspect it in the browser, but if you added `{{ generated_link }}` like `Go to Link {{ generated_link }}` the text there would be correct?

Comment: `mounted()` is run only on the [client side](https://nuxtjs.org/pt/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client). Still, I don't think that is anyhow related to the issue per-se. Did you tried to generate it locally? Still have the issue? Also, do you have a public Github repo or a [repro]?

Comment: Yes exactly @Bravo

Comment: As per @Kissu's recommendation, I tried making a minimum reproducible example. It appears to work in the new project, though. (Even just pasting the problem page into the new project it immediately works in production.) I suppose there must be something wrong with a package I am using or otherwise in my config?

Comment: I've never seen the same data have two different values at once - is that even possible? maybe it's a nuxt thing - or a typo

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a public repo. I will try to find the issue and post the answer if I do. I just can't imagine where to start looking- what in my config/ the way the project is set up could possibly cause this? Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the href of the 'a' tag is not actually bound to generated_link. It seems to be assigned during the build step and then can't change.

Comment: Have you declared the `generated_link` in the data of your component?

Comment: Yes I have, @kapcash. I've also tried making it a computed property but that didn't work either.